# API JMF ou Algo Similar Multiplataforma

Tags: java, java-ee

Tenho um projeto para fazer em java, que irei precisar do JMF para trabalhar com as midias em geral, o projeto nada mais é que um programa para rodar os anuncios nas TV's que ficam em shoppings e etc.

Me recomendaram usar o JMF, nunca tinha ouvido falar, estou estudando ele por agora, mas acabei vendo muita gente falando sobre ele ter sido descontinuado, ter parado no tempo enfim, Vocês tem algo em mente para que eu possa substituir o JMF e Que seja MultiPlataformas?